# looping through text file to find string with strinkTokenizer

Tags: java, while-loop, stringtokenizer

I am trying to loop through a text file, and according to my logic it is supposed to loop though while, line is not null, and then in another `while loop` inside of that loop, its supposed to loop through the line while a variable does not equal one of my command line arguments and then its supposed to take the first token of the line and add it to that variable. But every time I run the code I get no such element exception, i don't understand why?

```
try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = br.readLine();
        String id = new String();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        while(line != null){
            while(!id.equals(args[0])){
                line = br.readLine();
                id = st.nextToken();
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("file not found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("not a string");
    }
```

The file looks something like this:

line1: 118, s, m, p

line2: 111, s, m, c

Comment: You're reading the second line before checking any tokens on the first line.  Probably you want to move `line = br.readLine();` to be after the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

`nextToken()`

> NoSuchElementException--This is thrown if there are no more tokens in
>   this tokenizer's string

At this code

```
while(!id.equals(args[0])){

                id = st.nextToken();
            }
```

Your loop will continue until your while condition(`while(!id.equals(args[0]))`) fails. So check your `args[0]` with `id` by printing them on console before your while condition.

Modify your code a little bit

```
 String line ="";
        String id = new String();

    while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        while(!id.equals(args[0])){

            id = st.nextToken();
        }
    }
```

Your file contains `118, s, m, p` .. a space after `,` so I guess your tockenizer string should be `", "`